# Unable to use process.env to get environment variable in ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile in Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am trying to get environment variables in a node.js (using node-webkit) application on Mac and I am unable to.

I added the entry

export MY_PROJECT=\Library\MrProject

in both ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile.

I did source both and when I try to access process.env.MY_PROJECT it returns undefined. I tried to access process.env and it runs few things but it doesn't return the environment variables I am exporting in ~/.profile and/or ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: In your shell, what does `echo $MY_PROJECT` output? Are you sure the dotfiles you're editing are the same dotfiles used by the user owning the node process? Maybe try running this `export TEST=123; node -pe "process.env.TEST"` as a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `source ~/.bash_profile` when you modify profile files. Or logout and login to make it take into effect. Try replacing `process.env.MY_PROJECT` with `process.env.PATH` to test.